# Integrate Application Insights in Outsystems

Tags: azure-application-insights, outsystems

What is a good approach to send Application Insights telemetry from OutSystems to App Insights?

I see 2 levels:

- Server side
- Client side (browser)

Note: I have no experience with Outsystems.

Comment: Is your Outsystems platform hosted on Azure? If so, you should be able to access the Outsystems tables in Azure. If not, you might require to pass the information from Outsystems to Azure App Insight. e.g. expose an API in Azure and consume it from Outsystems.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know. Regardless of Outsystems version you use (10th or 11th), the best practice is to get rid of unnecessary load to the server, so the client side should be better.